# sudo port install winetricks error

Tags: wine

So i have installed wine `sudo port install wine` and also made sure I had made the following two d-bus processess:

```
$ sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.freedesktop.dbus-system.plist
$ launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/org.freedesktop
```

However when i `$ sudo port install winetricks`  i get the following error results:

```
--->  Computing dependencies for winetricks
--->  Dependencies to be installed: zenity webkit-gtk3 geoclue2 libsoup gmake gstreamer1-gst-plugins-base gstreamer1 gzip harfbuzz-icu libsecret gsed libgcrypt libgpg-error py27-simplejson webp yelp-tools yelp-xsl
--->  Building libsoup
Error: org.macports.build for port libsoup returned: command execution failed
Error: Failed to install libsoup
Please see the log file for port libsoup for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: zenity webkit-gtk3 geoclue2 libsoup gmake gstreamer1-gst-plugins-base gstreamer1 gzip harfbuzz-icu libsecret gsed libgcrypt libgpg-error py27-simplejson webp yelp-tools yelp-xsl
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
Error: Processing of port winetricks failed
```

Any thougts on making sure i install those dependencies? I have not found documentation.

EDIT: Here is the error log content

```
:debug:main changing euid/egid - current euid: 0 - current egid: 0
:debug:main egid changed to: 501
:debug:main euid changed to: 501
:debug:main Executing org.macports.main (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.archivefetch (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.fetch (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.checksum (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.extract (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.patch (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:main Skipping completed org.macports.configure (libsoup)
:debug:main Privilege de-escalation not attempted as not running as root.
:debug:build build phase started at Wed Jul  1 05:21:43 CDT 2015
:notice:build --->  Building libsoup
:debug:build Executing proc-pre-org.macports.build-build-0
:debug:build Executing org.macports.build (libsoup)
:debug:build Environment: 
CC_PRINT_OPTIONS='YES'
CC_PRINT_OPTIONS_FILE='/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/.CC_PRINT_OPTIONS'
CPATH='/opt/local/include'
LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/local/lib'
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET='10.10'
:debug:build Assembled command: 'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all CC="/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64"'
:debug:build Executing command line:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all CC="/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64" 
:info:build make: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0'
:info:build /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
:info:build make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0'
:info:build Making all in libsoup
:info:build make[2]: Entering directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0/libsoup'
:info:build ./tld-parser.py ../data/effective_tld_names.dat tld_data.inc
:info:build env: python: No such file or directory
:info:build make[2]: *** [tld_data.inc] Error 127
:info:build make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0/libsoup'
:info:build make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
:info:build make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0'
:info:build make: *** [all] Error 2
:info:build make: Leaving directory `/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0'
:info:build Command failed:  cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/work/libsoup-2.50.0" && /usr/bin/make -j4 -w all CC="/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64" 
:info:build Exit code: 2
:error:build org.macports.build for port libsoup returned: command execution failed
:debug:build Error code: CHILDSTATUS 43668 2
:debug:build Backtrace: command execution failed
    while executing
"system -nice 0 $fullcmdstring"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval system $notty $nice \$fullcmdstring"
    invoked from within
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"portbuild::build_main org.macports.build"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
"eval $procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: targets not executed for libsoup: org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:error:build Failed to install libsoup
:debug:build Registry error: yelp-xsl not registered as installed & active.
    invoked from within
"registry_active $subport"
    invoked from within
"$workername eval registry_active \$subport"
:notice:build Please see the log file for port libsoup for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_gnome_libsoup/libsoup/main.log
```

Comment: Do as the error message says. What does the log say?

Comment: How do i pull the log file?

Comment: The file given is just a text file so use your usual viewer/editor

Comment: Added the log file results

Comment: That looks like a bug to me - libsoup should depend on python. Report to the macports trac

Comment: I just completed the bug report!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions in the [macports guide.](https://guide.macports.org/)
Make a copy of the the log file. Clean the port then attempt to install the application again. File a bug report if the installation fails.